# tcolorbox styles deriving from each other

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, tikz-styles

The `listing` package allow to easily define styles and environment that derives from each other, which is very practical to avoid to copy and paste a lot of code. I am trying to see how to do the same with `tcolorbox`.

Consider the following code as an example:

```
% Document class
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, onecolumn]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Style
\newtcblisting{codebox}[4][\small]{
    before upper = {\topskip0pt \maxdepth=0pt},
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    breakable = unlimited,
    top = 0em,
    bottom = 0em,
    left = 0pt,
    right = 0pt,
    arc = 0em,
    outer arc = 0em,
    boxsep = 0em,
    boxrule = 0.5mm,
    titlerule = 0em,
    colback = white,
    colframe = blue,
    title = \centering#2,
    listing options = {
        language = C++,
        basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        #3,
    },
    #4,
}
\newtcblisting{codebox*}[4][\normalsize]{
    before upper = {\topskip0pt \maxdepth=0pt},
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    breakable = unlimited,
    top = 0em,
    bottom = 0em,
    left = 0pt,
    right = 0pt,
    arc = 0em,
    outer arc = 0em,
    boxsep = 0em,
    boxrule = 0.5mm,
    titlerule = 0em,
    colback = white,
    colframe = black,
    title = \centering#2,
    listing options = {
        language = Python,
        basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        #3,
    },
    #4,
}

% Document
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{codebox}{C++ listing example}{}{}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{codebox}
\begin{codebox*}{Python listing example}{}{}
def f(x):
    return x * x
\end{codebox*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Two environments are defined, `codebox` and `codebox*` with very few differences between the two (including the default parameter which is not the same). Would it be possible to have one sort of deriving of the other, to avoid to copy and paste all the options for environments that are close to each other. One constraint is that I would like the interface from the user side, to stay the same (`\begin{codebox}{}{}{}` or `\begin{codebox}[]{}{}{}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what styles are for. This example puts the common keys into a style `common`, which is used by both boxes.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, onecolumn]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{common/.style={before upper = {\topskip0pt \maxdepth=0pt},
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    breakable = unlimited,
    top = 0em,
    bottom = 0em,
    left = 0pt,
    right = 0pt,
    arc = 0em,
    outer arc = 0em,
    boxsep = 0em,
    boxrule = 0.5mm,
    titlerule = 0em,
    colback = white,  
 }}

% Style
\newtcblisting{codebox}[4][\small]{common,colframe = blue,title = \centering#2,
   listing options = {
        language = C++,
        basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        #3,
    },
    #4,
}
\newtcblisting{codebox*}[4][\normalsize]{common,
    colframe = black,
    title = \centering#2,
    listing options = {
        language = Python,
        basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        #3,
    },
    #4,
}

% Document
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{codebox}{C++ listing example}{}{}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{codebox}
\begin{codebox*}{Python listing example}{}{}
def f(x):
    return x * x
\end{codebox*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I do it if I don't want my style to be under `common` but let say under `commoncodebox`?

Comment: @Vincent You can call the style as you want, i.e. you can just replace `common` by `commoncodebox` everywhere in the code and it will still work.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was a default thing defined in the tcolorbox package.